# Solving the PDE for elastic filament in viscous liquid

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, finite-difference-methods

I want to solve the following 4th order PDE with the boundary conditions as written. It would be really helpful if someone could guide me on how to solve this. I have tried implicit finite differencing as well as inbuilt solvers in mathematica and matlab. If there are numerical solvers I can directly use, please let me know.

$y_t = -4y_{xxxx}$

Boundary conditions :
$y(x=0) = 0 \\
y_x(x=0) = a_0\sin{\omega t} \\
y_{xx}(x=L) = 0 \\
y_{xxx}(x=L) = 0\\$

Comment: This PDE has general solution (from separation of variables): $y(x,t)=e^{-4k^4t}\left[Ae^{kx}+Be^{-kx}+C\sin{kx}+D\cos{kx}\right]$ ($k$ may be complex). This is incompatible with your second boundary condition, are you sure you have this down correctly?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have seen this analytical solution elsewhere as well, but I am interested in finding numerical solutions because this PDE is actually a linear approximation to a more complicated PDE.

Any solvers or packages perhaps?